# Jasmine - How to test errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

**THE SITUATION:**

Hello guys. I am learning jasmine to test my angular app.

I have create a basic function that does multiply two numbers.
If the parameters given are not a number, the function throw an error.

I then made two very basic tests.

The first to check if the function properly multiply the numbers.
The second to check if the function properly throw an error if a string is given as parameter.

The first test pass, the second not. And i don't understand why.

**THE CODE:**

**The function:**

```
function Multiply( num1, num2 )
{

    var result;

    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) 
    {
        throw new Error("not a number");
    }
    else
    {
        result = num1 * num2;

        return result;
    }

}
```

**The spec:**

```
describe('The function', function () 
{
    it('properly multiply two numbers', function () 
    {
        result = Multiply(10, 5);
        expect(result).toEqual(50);
    });

    it('throw an error if a parameter is not a number', function () 
    {
        result = Multiply(10, 'aaaa');

        expect(result).toThrow(new Error("not a number"));

    });

});
```

**THE OUTPUT:**

```
2 specs, 1 failure
Spec List | Failures
The function throw an error if a parameter is not a number
Error: not a number
Error: not a number
    at Multiply (http://localhost/jasmine_test/src/app.js:8:9)
```

If i understand properly Jasmine. Both test should pass, because in the second case the function throw the error as we expected.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i test if a function properly throw an error?

**EDIT:**

I am trying this new code, but is still not working:

```
describe('The function', function () 
{

    it('throw an error if a parameter is not a number', function () 
    {

        expect(function() { Multiply(10, 'aaaa') }).toThrowError(new Error("not a number"));

    });

});
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2 specs, 1 failure
Spec List | Failures
The function throw an error if a parameter is not a number
Error: Expected is not an Error, string, or RegExp.
```

Comment: You need to run it in an anonymous function passed as "expect" argument. `expect(function() { Multiply(10, 'aaaa') })` - otherwise jasmine doesn't have chance to capture it

Comment: you would need `.toThrowError(Error, "not a number")`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to pass a function into the `expect(...)` call.

The code you have here:

```
expect(result).toThrow(new Error("not a number"));
```

Is checking the result of Multiply, which when it works is fine, but like I said .toThrow() expects a function, I'd use an anonymous function instead, see below:

```
expect( function(){ Multiply(10, 'aaaa'); } ).toThrow(new Error("not a number"));
```

EDIT: Did a quick search and [this](https://ajsblackbelt.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/jasmine-tests-expect-tothrow/) blog post is a very detailed explanation of what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the code you expect to throw an error into a function:

```
expect(function () {
    Multiply(10, 'aaaa');
}).toThrow(Error, 'not a number');
```

Otherwise, when you run your assertions, the error has already been thrown outside the scope. You can see available syntax for error matching in [jasmine docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction)

Comment: can also use this `expect( () => { Multiply(10, 'aaaa'); }).toThrow(new Error('not a number'));`

Answer (score 0):

- The above methods are exactly true for exceptions handled inside the methods.
- When you've to test the services you can use **`mocking mechanism`** to do that.
- Use the advantage of **NgModule providers** section to create the mocks.
- In describe() block,

```js
providers: [{ provide: APIService, useValue: { api: { filterTaskDetails: () => throwError('Error') }}}]
```

> `throwError` to be imported from `rxjs`.

- In expect() block test it as,

```js
spyOn(component['toaster'], 'showError');
/** add respected it() blocks**/
expect(component['toaster'].showError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```